# How to render jqvmap without border?

Tags: jqvmap

I am using jqvmap to render clickable world map. I set borderWidth=0 but still it is giving border to each country. I want all maps with no border. Seems like I will need to set some other property along with borderWidth.

If no possible then how I can set map fill color to border for selected countries so it will look like no border.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply setting the BorderColor parameter to the same color as the map I was able to make them "disappear".  Looking at the jquery.vmap.js I see that there is a condition such that the parameter passed along with the map for setting the border width will only be used if it's greater than 0, so you can either a) set the border to the same color as the map or b) modify the jquery.vmap.js to set the border to 0 as a default.  I've tried both and got the desired result.

Comment: You are right. It is working. Now the issue is when I set a different color to show few countries to form a continent then also it is taking the same color which actually forms a border.
How can I change border color of selected countries only?

Comment: well, here's the bad and good-ish news.  there isn't a defined property to set the border color of a selected region.  this means modifying jquery.vmap.js.  In the "selected" event I added this line: `path.setAttribute("stroke", this.selectedColor);` to the condition that checks for the selected color.  this will color the shape outline the same as the region.  the not so great news is that it isn't a perfect fill, I suspect because of overlapping shapes, possibly.  However, it gets you 99.9% of the way there.

Comment: Sorry for deplayed reply. it didn't work for me. Seems like it is not border color but there is a space between two countries which is looking like border. When I changed the background color then I found it.